# How to configure Maven build for Java project with external dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, build, jar

I'm trying to create automated solution for building with maven. My vision is to have a Maven build, which creates JAR file from my project and then just copies all the dependencies as JARs to some sub-directory in "target" folder.

I do not want to use Shade or Assembly (so I do not want to extract the content of other JARs and include it in one "super-JAR", because the project is more complicated and it breaks when I'm including all the JARs in one file).

How can I do such build POM?

Comment: All the dependencies are copied over to target/lib when you do a maven build.

Comment: @AjayGeorge that very much depends on the `<packaging>`.. The OP stated that he builds a JAR, so nothing will be in his `target/lib`. @Miroslav I'm curious why you don't want to use the assembly plugin?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup You mean to build one single superjar file? It would be the best, but I kept struggling with overwritten / skipped files (as for now, the project has 68 external JARs it depends on) - even Shade did not helped... so I ended up with one messed up JAR file unable to properly start... as I said in my comment below the accepted answer, I'm struggling with Maven configuration.

Comment: Yes that's what I would do, but @IgorKonoplyanko 's answer is much better, and so I learned something as well :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see here any problem. Just create maven pom.xml with `<packaging>jar</packaging>`
By default it should not pack into your jar all dependent libraries.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: There is no problem, I'm just failing (for a long time) to get a grip on Maven configuration and I don't have time to properly study it, because of other work. :-( Thank you, this is basically the answer. Now I just have to figure out how to add the manifest in the same step, but I think I can deal with that. THANK YOU!

Comment: Most valuable tip for novice I can advice - try 'mvn archetype:generate'. there you can get ready setups of maven for different types of projects.

Answer (score 2):

Related with your latest comment, use this plugin to add the main class in the manifest:

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.test.YourMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out already. And, as java -jar somehow overrides (?) java -cp, I ended up using java -cp "project-jarfile.jar;lib/*" mainClass anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven-assembly-plugin to create a .zip file from a selection of other files in your directory.  I have used this method to create distribution zip files for a project.  There are several examples available in the [maven-assembly-plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not it. Assembly plugin is the last step of the process, creating distribution bundle. But I needed just to gather the dependencies in a single directory first.